# ASP.NET - can't insert data and hours in database (dataset)

Tags: asp.net, database, dataset

I'm creating an application where people can insert an event with information such as eventname, location, date, hours, ...

There are 3 steps. the first 2 steps with the inserts were succesfully inserted. But at step 3 where they have to insert a startDay (Startdag), endDay(Einddag), starthour(startUurt), endHour(eindUur) I can't get it fixed.

In the presentationlayer I'm using the calendarExtender for Startday and Endday with format d MMMM yyyy with and target txt_sDag and txt_eDag

In dataset "DAL_Planit3.xsd" I've given endDay and startDay as type "datetime" and startHour and endHour as type String (becoz we will only read it, we won't be doing anything with it).

Can someone please help me?

***StepThree.aspx.vb***

```
Protected Sub btn_next_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_next.Click
        Try

            Dim BLLdata As New BLL_Data
            Dim eventID As Integer = Session.Item("eventID")
            Dim plaatsID As Integer = Session.Item("plaatsID")
            Dim data As New CL_Data

            data.Einddag = txt_eDag.Text
            data.Startdag = CDate(txt_sDag.Text)
            data.Einddag = CDate(txt_eDag.Text)
            data.Einduur = txt_eUur.Text
            data.StartUur = txt_sUur.Text
            data.FKEvenementId = eventID
            data.FKPlaatsId = plaatsID

            BLLdata.insertData(data)

            lbl_feedback.Text = "Data succesful inserted!"

        Catch ex As Exception
            lbl_feedback.Text = "Data not inserted! " + ex.Message
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

***BLL_Data.vb***

```
' INSERT DATA
Public Function insertData(ByVal data As CL_Data) As String
    Dim feedback As String = Nothing

    Try

        adapterDatum3.Insert(data.Startdag, data.Einddag, data.StartUur, data.Einduur, data.FKPlaatsId, data.FKEvenementId)
        'adapterDatum.Insert(data.Startdag, data.Einddag, data.StartUur, data.Einduur, data.FKPlaatsId, data.FKEvenementId)
        feedback = "Data is toegevoegd"
    Catch ex As Exception
        feedback = ex.Message
    End Try

    Return feedback

End Function
```

**CL_Data**

```
Public Class CL_Data

    Private iDataId As Integer
    Public Property DataID() As Integer
        Get
            Return iDataId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            iDataId = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private dStartDag As Date
    Public Property Startdag() As Date
        Get
            Return dStartDag
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            dStartDag = value

        End Set
    End Property


    Private dEindDag As Date
    Public Property Einddag() As Date
        Get
            Return dEindDag
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            dEindDag = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private tStartUur As String
    Public Property StartUur() As String
        Get
            Return tStartUur
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            tStartUur = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private tEindUur As String
    Public Property Einduur() As String
        Get
            Return tEindUur
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            tEindUur = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private iFKPlaatsId As Integer
    Public Property FKPlaatsId() As Integer
        Get
            Return iFKPlaatsId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            iFKPlaatsId = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private iFKEvenementId As Integer
    Public Property FKEvenementId() As Integer
        Get
            Return iFKEvenementId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            iFKEvenementId = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting (i.e.  the value of EX.Message) in the first code window?

Comment: There's no error message. I get my message that it's inserted, which is not.

Comment: But you don't capture the Feedback value from your InsertData function, which might be the one causing the error...